# subtraction in query (SUM)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this query that have this output (the correct):

```
15
44
```

Query:

```
  SELECT T.numContribuinte, 
         T.numero, 
         SUM(C.valor - T.valorTotalChamadas) AS saldo
    FROM telemovel T
    JOIN CARREGAMENTO C ON C.numero = T.numero
GROUP BY T.numContribuinte, T.numero
  HAVING saldo > 0
ORDER BY T.numero DESC
```

If I remove the word sum the output will be:

```
15
15
```

### My question is

Why the absence of the sum produce this difference in the output?

Comment: You should provide more information, what are the records in telemovel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that [by design, MySQL allows columns in the SELECT to not be stated in the `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions (MAX, MIN, COUNT, etc)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).  The caveat to this functionality is the values returned are arbitrary -- they can't be guaranteed to be consistent every time.

The support is in line with what's dictated by ANSI, but few (SQLite only to my knowledge) support this behavior.  Others require the column to either be mentioned in the `GROUP BY` or enclosed in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

When you `GROUP BY` some columns, you ask MySQL to take all rows with identical values in those columns, and replace those rows with only one row in the result set. MySQL needs to know from which of those many rows you want each column's value to be in the one row returned. You must use an aggregate function to describe that, like `MIN` to select the smallest value, `MAX` to select the largest value, or `SUM` to select the sum of all the values being replaced.

If you fail to specify an aggregate function, MySQL will take the value from any row it wants. Which row it takes the value from may be different when you run the same query more than once -- the behavior is not defined.